# Sample Dataset for Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters, estimation

I'm a newbie to Kalman filter. I have found the code online but I was wondering if there is any sample dataset available online to get hands-on with it (for example: CIFAR-10 for classification etc. ).

Comment: What is CIFAR-10?  A KF is a state estimator, not a classification algorithm. A classifier might use a KF in some hypothetical way but this wouldn’t be something a newbie interested in KF would start with.

Comment: Could you mark an answer or comment what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create measurement for Kalman Filter model.
Just run the model itself on some noise with starting point and you'll have endless number of data points.

Namely, if your model is given by:

$$ x \left[ k \right] = F x \left[ k - 1 \right] + v \left[ k \right] $$

Then all you need is to generate $ x \left[ 0 \right] $ randomly according to $ P \left[ 0 \right] $ and start moving it according to the above model while generating $ v \left[ k \right] $.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a sample data set for the Kalman filter.

There is no one Kalman filter, and the "filter" part of the name isn't so much of a misnomer, as a use of the word stretches its meaning somewhat.

A Kalman filter is a filter, usually multivariate, that is designed to take the inputs to and the outputs from *a specific known system*, and use those inputs and outputs to estimate (AKA "observe") the states of the system.

The Kalman filter that you'd design to observe the states of a wind turbine will be *completely different* from the Kalman filter you'd design to observe the states of a multicopter, and completely different yet again to observe the internal states of an induction motor.

If you are modeling *a* system well enough to use that model for a Kalman filter, then you can also use that system model to generate a set of test vectors.  You can, in fact, generate your test vectors online, far easier than you can execute the Kalman filter.

But there is, by no means ever, a single one-size-fits-all dataset that fits every possible Kalman filter.